# How to send openvpn syslog?

Tags: openvpn, rsyslog, rsyslogd

I'm trying to figure out how I can send openvpn syslog message to a remote server. Openvpn documentation is non existent but according to server.conf messages should be forwarded to syslog by default if you disable to local log files. I tried that and configured rsyslog as well with the help of google but its not working. I can send a udp test message to my remote server so I know its not a network/remote server issue.

I also tried imfile for rsyslog to see if I can at least send the /var/log/openvpn/openvpn-status.log content to my remote server but that isn't working either.

Openvpn and rsyslog both are thing on docs and don't seem to have any troubleshooting built in. I tried various solutions I found but nothing works.

Comment: If you want to keep also local log, you should try something like:

Create /etc/rsyslog.d/99-openvpn.conf and insert ->
:programname, startswith, "%openvpn" @remoteIP:remotePORT 

# This is not tested, just a suggestion.

Comment: Question is too broad:
1/ Can you see openvpn's log in syslog logs ?
2/ How did you configured your rsyslog ?

Comment: I can see the openvpn logs. Because openvpn syslog and rsyslog don't seem to have a straight forward way to forward logs I wrote a small script that simply curls the log file to my remote server where I have my receiving software process the input.